# window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches returns false in Android

Tags: android, cordova, media-queries, darkmode

I am working on a Cordova Application. I want to detect if the device has dark mode or light mode enabled. I used this code to do so `window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches`. it works fine for iOS but for Android it always returns false.

```
int darkModeEnabled = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches
alert('Dark Mode enabled: '+ darkModeEnabled);
```

I turned on Dark Mode in Android Settings. But it always returns false.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this plugin cordova-plugin-theme-detection
[to detect system theme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-theme-detection)